# Base64 Encoded String doesn't matches

Tags: java, android, encoding, base64

Im frustraded. I've got a Basic Http Authorization. For this I set a `HttpGet`Header.
This Header needs to be Base64 encoded. I do it like so:

```
String acc = uname + ":" + pword;
byte[] a = acc.getBytes();
String header = "Basic " + new String(Base64.encode(a, Base64.DEFAULT));
```

But this encoded String doesn't work. When I log the header, it prints out the same as I need.
It looks the same as `String h = "Basic c2NodWsZXI6aGVpbmNA==";` Which is the working one.
But when I compare `header.equals(h);` or `header==h` theire both `false`.
In the end when I set the header to `header`it doesn't work, but when I'm using `h` it works. I guess its sometehing about String encoding but I tried different ways of `.getBytes("UTF-8")` and similiar (ASCII, UTF-16) but they worked neither.
The username and password are normal chars and numbers.

Can anyone see the mistake? Thanks
Grevius

Comment: `header.equals(h)` returning false indicates that the strings are not identical. `header==h` shall return false since they are not the same reference. Try logging your `header` and `h` just before you compare them using `header.equals(h)`. Try `header.equalsIgnoreCase(h)` just in case.

Comment: `03-16 16:57:42.200: I/HHG(28725): Basic c2NodWsZXI6aGVpbmNA==
03-16 16:57:42.200: I/HHG(28725): Basic c2NodWsZXI6aGVpbmNA==` I'm logging them and they are equal to me. The `.equalsIgnoreCase` returns `false`

Comment: empty spaces perhaps? try `header.trim().equals(h.trim())`

Comment: Now that is `true`. Oh dear, now it works. I've just wasted 3 hours because of a stupid Whitespace, that nowhere showed up -.-
But where does it come from?

Comment: Hmm, that's hard to say. It could be from the `encode` function. Look into it later when you have time :)

Comment: Ok, then just answer my Question so I can tick it as right. Thanks man. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`header.equals(h)` returning false indicates that the strings are not identical. `header==h` shall return false since they are not the same reference.

Empty spaces perhaps? try `header.trim().equals(h.trim())`

Answer (score 0):

try using base64.encodestring(s)

Comment: there is no `Base64.encodestring` but a `.encodeToString`. I've tried that too, still don't works

Comment: Which version of python are you using. I see that api at http://docs.python.org/2/library/base64.html

Comment: None, I'm using java, as the tag says